# Javascript: Getting the parent object, in OOP composite pattern

Tags: javascript, oop, design-patterns, composite

My program implements the composite pattern, that looks more or less like that:

```
class Selector{
   constructor(){
       this.selectors=[]
   }

   addSelector(selector){
    this.selectors.push(selector);
  }

   processSelector(){
       this.selectors.forEach(selector=>selector.processSelector())
   }
}
```

What i'd like to know, is whether there's some way of giving the child object a reference to the parent one, without just passing the "this" in the addSelector() method. What i **don't want**, would look something like this:

```
addSelector(selector){
    selector.parent = this;
    this.selectors.push(selector);
}
```

I find this to be a bit "ugly". How would i just get the selectors array, in which the object is referenced(and then of course the object in which it sits)? In more general words: How to get the the array of an element?

Comment: Unless you do something "ugly" like explicitly link the child back to the parent via some explicit property, you cannot. Any number of objects (or variables) can hold references to another object, so which one would be **the** "parent"?

Comment: Well there will be only one parent, but from what i understand from you, it's just programmatically impossible, right? Edit: ok, i see in another post: "In Javascript, array elements have no reference to the array(s) containing them."

Comment: Right, there is no reference to the containing array. This makes sense when you consider a single object can be contained in arbitrarily many arrays.

Comment: Yes, i understand now, thank you both. I'll just take the "ugly" approach :-)